# Why am I getting a "perhaps a missing \item" error in my custom epigraph environment?

Tags: formatting, environments, epigraphs

I have tried to customised a new environment for epigraphs in a book. This page should have no fancy headers or anything alike. It should only have a list of one or more epigraphs. To that end I am using the epigraph package and I have defined the following in the .cls file:

```
\RequirePackage{epigraph}
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.56\textwidth}
    \let\oldqitem\qitem
    \renewcommand{\qitem}[3]{\oldqitem{\textit{#1}}{\textit{#2}\\\textsc{#3}}}

\newenvironment{epigpage}[1][10]{%begin
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \phantomsection
    \vspace*{#1\@line} %default 10
    \begin{epigraphs}\begin{flushright}
}{%end
    \end{flushright}\end{epigraphs}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \blankpage
}
```

The renew command for `\qitem` is done to distinguish between the book name and the authors name. Then I simply start a new empty page and begin the usual epigraphs environment.

Finally, in the .tex file what I do is the following:

```
\begin{epigpage}
    \qitem{``My favourite quote.''}{My favourite book}{My favourite authors}
\end{epigpage}
```

The problem is that when compiling I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
￼l.8    \qitem
       {``My favourite quote.''}{My favourite book}{My favourite authors}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think the problem stems from having the beginning and end of the `flushright` environment in two different groups. Try substituting `\begingroup\raggedleft` for `\begin{flushright}`, and `\endgroup` for `\end{flushright}`.

Comment: @Jubobs Thank you very much, that solved the problem :) This is the first time I am writing my own LaTeX template so I am not very good at it but keen to learn. By the way I was creating a compilable version but you already answered.

Comment: That's fine. In the future, please post an MWE, whenever possible. You're likely to get valuable help more quickly. By the way, [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Done! I am sorry, but I am completely new to this community and didn't know any of the things you mentioned :)

Comment: No problem. Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a new environment with a `flushright` environment nested inside a `epigraphs` environment, like so

```
\newenvironment{epigpage}
{
    \begin{epigraphs}
    \begin{flushright}
}{
  \end{flushright}
  \end{epigraphs}
}
```

will indeed produce the error you report.

<s>I didn't get to the root of the problem, but substituting `\begingroup\raggedleft` for `\begin{flushright}`, and `\endgroup` for `\end{flushright}` in your definition of `epigpage` seems to fix it.</s>

However, you don't even need that `flushright` environment because your epigraphs are already flushed to the rigth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}    % top show that the epigraphs
                                                                    % are already flushed to the right
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epigraph}
    \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.56\textwidth}
    \let\oldqitem\qitem
    \renewcommand{\qitem}[3]{\oldqitem{\textit{#1}}{\textit{#2}\\\textsc{#3}}}

\newenvironment{epigpage}[1][10]{%begin
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \phantomsection
    \vspace*{#1\baselineskip}   % I changed that because \@line was undefined
    \begin{epigraphs}
}{%end
    \end{epigraphs}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \cleardoublepage                    % I change that because \blankpage was undefined
}

\begin{document}
\begin{epigpage}
    \qitem{``My favourite quote.''}{My favourite book}{My favourite authors}
\end{epigpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what `\raggedleft` is supposed to do, as I see no difference with or without it; but enclosing it between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is surely wrong. Think about it: an end of paragraph command has issued by `\end{epigraph}` when the group is already ended together with the effect of `\raggedleft`. Try `\begingroup\raggedleft Something\endgroup\par` and see: the only visible effect is the missing indentation.

Comment: @egreg You may be right. I haven't dug into it that much. I'll investigate later. As always, thanks for the heads up.